# i18n custom block on Vue3 + Vite

Tags: vuejs3, vue-i18n

I have a Laravel + Inertja + Vue 3  project using Vite.

I installed i18n plugin to be able to manage UI translation.

Actually I have some json files for translations in /resources/locales
Here a little example from the it.json file

```
{
    "title": "Vue 3 i18n ita",
    "description": "Un esempio Vue i18n utilizzando vue-i18n-next",
    "hello": "Buongiorno mondo"
}
```

This is my Vite config

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import { quasar, transformAssetUrls } from '@quasar/vite-plugin';
import { resolve, dirname } from 'path';
import {fileURLToPath} from 'url';
import vueI18n from '@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
        quasar({
            sassVariables: 'resources/css/quasar-variables.sass'
        }),
        vueI18n({
            // if you want to use Vue I18n Legacy API, you need to set `compositionOnly: false`
            // compositionOnly: false,
      
            // you need to set i18n resource including paths !
            include: resolve(dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)), './resources/locales/**'),
          })      
    ],
    server: {
        hmr: {
            host: 'localhost',
        },
    }
});
```

This is my app.js

```
import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css';

import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import { ZiggyVue } from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.m';

import { Quasar } from 'quasar';
// Import icon libraries
import '@quasar/extras/material-icons/material-icons.css'
// Import Quasar css
import 'quasar/src/css/index.sass'

// for translations
import i18n from './i18n'

const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText || 'Laravel';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, app, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(app, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy)
            .use(Quasar, {
                plugins: {},
            } )
            .use(i18n)
            .mount(el);
    },
});

InertiaProgress.init({ color: '#4B5563' });
```

and here my /resources/js/i18n/index.js

```
import { createI18n } from "vue-i18n";
// import all the json files
/*
 * All i18n resources specified in the plugin `include` option can be loaded
 * at once using the import syntax
 */
import messages from '@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n/messages'


const i18n = createI18n({
    legacy: false,
    locale: 'it',
    fallbackLocale: 'it',
    messages
})


export default i18n
```

Now the page component I'm trying to translate:

```
<template>
    <GuestLayout>
        <Head title="Log in" />

        <div v-if="status" class="mb-4 font-medium text-sm text-green-600">
            {{ status }}
        </div>
        <label for="locale">locale</label>
  <select v-model="$i18n.locale">
    <option>en</option>
    <option selected>it</option>
  </select>
  
  <p>message: {{ $t('hello') }}</p>
  <p>nome in lingua: {{ $t('pato') }}</p>
....
....
</template>

<i18n locale="it">
{
    "pato" : "Marcolino"
}
</i18n>
<i18n locale="en">
{
    "pato" : "mr Patolino"
}
</i18n>
```

Now the "hello" resource it is showed accordingly to the choosen language; instead the "pato" resource is not working and it shows always 'pato'.... it seems it does not recognize custom block content.

I tried also changing the custom block in this way, without success.

```
<i18n>
{
    "it" : {
            "pato" : "Marcolino"
    },
    "en" : {
            "pato" : "mr Patolino"
    }
}
</i18n>
```

Where am I wrong? I don't understand....

Regards,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

According to the last version docs if you want to use the composition api, you need to do the following:

```js
<template>
...
  <p>nome in lingua: {{ t('named', { 'pato' }) }}</p>
...
</template>

<script>
import { computed } from 'vue'
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'

export default {
  setup() {
    const { t } = useI18n({
      locale: 'en',
      messages: {
        en: {
          msg: 'pato',
          named: "Mr. Patolino"
        },
        it: {
          msg: 'pato,
          named: 'Marcolino',
        }
      }
    })

    const msg = computed(() => t('msg'))

    return { t, msg }
  }
}
</script>
```

Find a similar example in docs [last version's docs](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/composition.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would only use one place to manage translations. Helpful is this package laravel-vue-i18n (https://github.com/xiCO2k/laravel-vue-i18n).

##### Installation

```bash
npm install laravel-vue-i18n
```

#### Setup i18n

**resources/js/app.js**

```js
import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css';

import { i18nVue } from 'laravel-vue-i18n';
import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import { ZiggyVue } from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.m';

const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText || 'Laravel';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(i18nVue, {
                lang: 'de',
                resolve: (lang) => import(`../../lang/${lang}.json`)
            })
            .use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy)
            .mount(el);
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#4B5563',
    },
});
```

**my lang-file in: lang/de.json and lang/en.json**

#### Frontend locale switcher

**Authenticated.vue**

```js
<script>
    import {getActiveLanguage, loadLanguageAsync} from 'laravel-vue-i18n';
</script>

<div v-if="getActiveLanguage() === 'en'">
    <a @click="loadLanguageAsync('de')" href="#"> Deutsch </a>
</div>
<div v-if="getActiveLanguage() === 'de'">
    <a @click="loadLanguageAsync('en')" href="#"> English </a>
</div>
```